# call to a member function result_array() on bool con limit superior a 600

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, model

Me encuentro trabajando con Codeigniter, php y sql server con una estructura MVC.
Tengo la siguiente función en el Model:

```
Class Vista_requirente_model extends General_model{

    public function __construct(){
        $table = 'vista_requirente';
        parent::__construct($table);
    }

    public function getFacFinanza(){
        $anio = date("Y");
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('vista_compras_finanza');
        $this->db->where('ano_fac', $anio);
        $this->db->limit(600);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $data = $query->result_array();
   
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Y al ejecutar, se obtiene el error **Uncaught error:call to a member function result_array() on bool**

Ironicamente, al cambiar el limit a 599, entrega los resultados como corresponde, sin embargo, la base de datos contiene mas de 1000 valores que necesito rescatar.

Sin importar la función que se trabaje con (result_array(), result(), num_rows(), etc.), cuando el limit es por sobre 600 arroja el mismo error, así como al cambiar el limit por 599, muestra los 599 registros como debería.

agradecería cualquier ayuda sobre el tema.

UPDATE: al agregar la linea:

```
if(!$query) { var_dump($this->db->error()); die(); }
```

El resultado es:

```
 array(2) { ["code"]=> string(9) "IMSSP/-59" ["message"]=> string(52) "Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query" }
```

Comment: ¿Problemas de memoria? Verifica en **php.ini**, el valor: `memory_limit=512M`

Comment: Antes de obtener los datos, verifica si hay error: `if(!$query) { die($this->db->error()); }` y agrega el mensaje a tu pregunta.

Comment: @aeportugal la memory_limit se encuentra en 1024M.

Comment: @Triby al agregar la linea, el resultado solamente es Array.

Comment: Cambia esa línea por `if(!$query) { var_dump($this->db->error()); die(); }` para ver lo que contiene el arreglo.

Comment: @Triby ahora dice  ["code"]=> string(9) "IMSSP/-59" ["message"]=> string(52) "Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query"

Comment: Ya podes cambiar el titulo y casi toda la pregunta, ahora que sabes que tu error es quedarte sin memoria al traer 600 filas... ;)

Comment: 600 registros [normales] no deberían ocupar casi nada en memoria. Parece que cada registro está trayendo muchisima información. Intenta no usar `SELECT * ...` y trae solo las columnas concretas. Otro potencial problema es que puede ser que haya columnas con data binaria, como imágenes (malísima práctica), en ese caso el consumo de memoria de la aplicación será cada vez mayor a medida que crezca la BD. Recomiendo optimizar el modelo, por ejemplo, guardar imagenes en disco y en la BD solo poner la referencia, si no es posible, usar paginación.

Comment: @aeportugal el problema finalmente era la falta de las lineas que especifique en la respuesta de más abajo. Pero gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muchas gracias por las respuestas, intente modificar el php.ini buscando que ocurría con el limite de memoria e investigando un poco más, resulto que faltaban las siguientes lineas:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
client_buffer_max_kb_size = '50240'
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize = 50240
```

al agregarlas ya podemos recoger los registros.

el resultado final fue de unos 3000 registros app. El software externo que provee esta base de datos es el que estaba complicando la situación para obtener la información.